# I need a rule that allows me to ban the usages of a form-validator

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

We made our own version of the Validators.required form-validator that is included in base Angular 7. It is mandatory that we use the new CustomValidators.required instead. We are looking into banning the usages of the old required by including it in our already existing TSlint config. We looked into the ban Rule https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ban/ 
But that doesn't seem to be working, we configured it as follows:

```
"ban": [
      true,
      "eval",
      {"name": ["Validators", "required"], "message": "Don't use the Validators.required use the CustomValidators.required instead!"}
    ]
```

We are at a loss currently, any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a custom rule to do exactly what I want it was easier that I thought.
I used this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBPhmzH0x64